# How to get Guzzle Promises to run asynchronously?

Tags: php, promise, guzzle

Repro:

```
<?php
use GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise;
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$promise1 = new Promise(function() use (&$promise1) {
    print 'PROMISE 1 FIRED' . PHP_EOL;
    sleep(2);

    $promise1->resolve('foo');
});

$promise2 = new Promise(function() use (&$promise2) {
    print 'PROMISE 2 FIRED' . PHP_EOL;
    sleep(2);

    $promise2->resolve('bar');
});

$promises = [$promise1, $promise2];
$results = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\unwrap($promises);

var_dump($results);
```

And the dump is:

```
//PROMISE 1 FIRED
//PROMISE 2 FIRED <-- fires after 2 seconds, and not immediately
//array(2) {
//    [0]=>
//  string(3) "foo"
//    [1]=>
//  string(3) "bar"
//}
```

Right now, `PROMISE 2 FIRED` prints after 2 seconds, and not immediately.

**How do I get it to print immediately?**

Comment: You made it sleep in the first `Promise` for two seconds, so remove that (`sleep(2);`)?

Comment: @Rasclatt hehe, sure, but that doesn't solve the problem. I intentionally put the sleep() there to demonstrate the problem.